# Android sqlite database export/import working but not displaying data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, import, export

I am on my 10+ hour of trying to get my sqlite database to export to sdcard as a backup and then import information back to my application.   I have searched every topic I could to try and figure this out without having to ask any questions but now I have ran out of helpful info.   I seem to be very very close to finishing this... Here's where I am:   I am following this basic example http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=importexport-android-database .   Everything seems to be working great and I can see the folder I created with my backup file and if I open the file as text I can see it is saving my information from my db.   I then import my saved file back to my application and everything seems to go well also.   The problem is the new information I load from my backup isn't displayed in my application, it still displays the same data as before the import.   The weird thing is if I export my database after importing it the export file is the correct data that was supposed to be displayed, so I am apparently getting the correct data when I import it just doesn't show up and instead shows whatever old data I had before import.   Again, it works however, just doesn't seem to refresh my data my application is reading.   Thank you for any help with this, I am stumped.

Here is my import

```
    myOutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/my_project/databases/empdb.db");


            // Set the folder on the SDcard
            File directory = new File("/sdcard/CarMaintenanceBackup");
            // Set the input file stream up:

   InputStream myInputs = new FileInputStream(directory.getPath()+ "/empdb.backup");



            // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = myInputs.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }


            // Close and clear the streams
            myOutput.flush();


            myOutput.close();

            myInputs.close();   



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   Toast.makeText(mymenu.this, "Import Unsuccesfull!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {   Toast.makeText(mymenu.this, "Import Unsuccesfull!", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(mymenu.this, "Import Done Succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

edit*
my OpenHelper

```
    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }






    public OpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CARINFO_TABLE);

        db.execSQL(HISTORY_TABLE);

        db.execSQL(MPG_TABLE);

        db.execSQL(MODS_TABLE);

        db.execSQL(PICK_TABLE);

        //UPDATE//

        db.execSQL(VEHICLENAME_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(ODOMETER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(COUNTER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(SETTIME5_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(USORMETRIC_TABLE);



        }





    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg2 > arg1) {
            db.execSQL(PICK_TABLE);

            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Employees ADD COLUMN _datetask INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this method in onCreate? or onResume? Not enough to judge by!

Comment: You are showing the code that imports the backup, but your problem is not with that but with the code that refreshes your app's display with that data.

Comment: Would restarting the activity refresh the display?   I have many classes where data is displayed and switching through them nothing changes.   the above code is called in onCreateOptionsMenu ---> onOptionsItemSelected.   I will play around with the way I implement this next chance I have more time.   I am self taught and fairly new to android so there could very possibly be something I am overlooking.   Any pointers on how I should refresh the data?   Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried working on this some more with no luck to speak of.   I have a suspicion it is due to my OpenHelper.   I have much more determination than experience when it comes this...